# nginx basic auth can't disable

Tags: nginx, server, .htpasswd

I tested the auth basic in nginx by adding auth_basic and auth_basic_user_file in the default conf/ Also I used

> htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd admin

to create a password file. The problem is when I want to disable it.

I have removed auth_basic and auth_basic_user_file, restarted nginx, removed the htpasswd file and restart again and the website is still asking for username and password. I also restarted the server and clear the cache in my browser. Does anyone has an idea what is happening and how I can get rid of this issue?

Comment: make sure there's no reference or configuration on nginx.conf and then reboot the server. Most probably, it's not restarting the service properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys for this question ... this is happening when departments don't know how to talk. The website is a Wordpress installation and someone installed a plugin that is authenticating like the auth basic. So I was viewing the first auth screen the auth_basic and the second because of the plugin.